# Advertisement is flying down inside iframe - CSS mistake?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I had been researching to convert my fixed width/height iframes of my gaming portal to be responsive and i found a bunch of different suggestions from people, out of which i made a CSS addition targeted at my iframe class which worked very well to make everything responsive, but when I tested on ipad specifically using the Safari browser the ad which appears in the beginning of the games starts flying down and therefore makes it impossible for the game to begin.

**Could you please help me correct this problem?**
Here are more details:

Inside my article I have my iframe where the game is embedded in the following code:

```
<center>
<div class="game-responsive-container" style="padding-bottom: 66.81%;">
  <iframe src="GAMEURL" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
</center>
```

FYI1: The class "game-responsive-container" is what I target in my CSS (shown below).
FYI2: The padding-bottom part is dedicated per page because each game could have a different height.

In my CSS I have the following related to this question:

```
.game-responsive-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.game-responsive-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

So again from what I can tell it works very well on the computer but on Safari browser something creates a problem where visually you see the ad appear in the center of the iframe and then fly down until it disappears and consequently the game does not load anymore making it impossible to play.

From some additional testing it is my impression that the height and width are being enlarged and the ad is naturally moving towards the larger center thus giving this flying visual. Once I did manage to see the background of the game which was just the top left part of the game screen which made me think that the game has loaded on a much larger area in the background.

Here is an example URL: http://dolygames.com/cube-ninja-play-free/
(Note: there are some games from a different provider which do not have this problem, so i did consider that this could be some wrong code from this specific provider but when i had fixed iframe with fixed width/height then everything worked)

I hope my information was detailed enough and I hope someone may be able to help me to fix this problem so that everyone can enjoy my gaming portal. Thanks in advance to all who help.